# What type of tortoise is this?

Tags: species-identification

Found him on the street in San Antonio subdivision unsure of what type of tortoise he might be.

[image]

Comment: A photo of the underside and hind legs would be most helpful for precise ID. From the location and limited visual, it looks like a young [Texas Tortoise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lzhS46WPK0) which is an endangered species. Very cute!